# Concatenating two columns from different table and using them as WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select top 100 * 
from ProductionPeriodic.dbo.ScanDataRaw
where sdr_ID in (
    select concat(rsw_dept, rsw_rsm_id_fk) 
    from [dbo].[RollSheetArchiveDetails] rsad
    inner join dbo.RollSheetMain rsm on rsad.rsw_rsm_id_fk = rsm.rsm_id 
    where rsw_PoNo = 'UHB800008'
    and rsm_status = 'R'
)
and sdr_ScanDate = '30/09/2022'
```

sdr_ScanDate is a string.

There are two values concatenated.

However, the query does not stop executing

Comment: How large are these tables?

Comment: RollSheetMain is 5 million rows and RollSheetArchiveDetails is 1.2million rows

Answer (score 1):

My presumption is that the subquery *should* run fast, but my hypothesis is that the query optimizer is doing the full join before applying the filters.

I would start by ensuring that

```
select rsw_dept, rsw_rsm_id_fk 
    from [dbo].[RollSheetArchiveDetails] rsad
    inner join dbo.RollSheetMain rsm on rsad.rsw_rsm_id_fk = rsm.rsm_id 
    where rsw_PoNo = 'UHB800008'
    and rsm_status = 'R'
```

runs quickly.  If it does not, you probably need to either add indices or re-work this to align with the indices you have.

After that, it also needs to be the case that

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM   ProductionPeriodic.dbo.ScanDataRaw
WHERE  sdr_ID IN ('id1', 'id2')
AND    sdr_ScanDate = '30/09/2022'
```

also runs fast.  Again, if not optimize this part independently.

If both of those are the case though the optimizer is probably getting tripped up by your correlated subquery.  You probably want to make this a proper join:

```
SELECT TOP 100 ScanDataRaw.* 
FROM        ProductionPeriodic.dbo.ScanDataRaw
INNER JOIN  (   SELECT DISTINCT 
                    sw_dept, 
                    rsw_rsm_id_fk 
                FROM        [dbo].[RollSheetArchiveDetails]
                INNER JOIN  dbo.RollSheetMain 
                ON          RollSheetArchiveDetails.rsw_rsm_id_fk = RollSheetMain.rsm_id 
                WHERE       rsw_PoNo = 'UHB800008'
                AND         rsm_status = 'R'
            ) AS IdParts
ON          ScanDataRaw.sdr_ID = IdParts.rsw_dept + IdParts.rsw_rsm_id_fk
WHERE       ScanDataRaw.sdr_ScanDate = '30/09/2022'
```

If the query optimizer still cannot figure out that the IdParts subquery executes quickly and returns few rows, you can try to force it to try each of the 3 physical joins using INNER LOOP JOIN, INNER HASH JOIN, and INNER MERGE JOIN, and you can try them each in the ScanDataRaw JOIN IdParts order and the IdParts JOIN ScanDataRaw order.  Whichever of these 6 options is the fastest can become your query.

Ideally, though, it will be able to figure it out on its own without you having to specify a particular physical join.

Comment: every part runs smoothly except
WHERE       ScanDataRaw.sdr_ScanDate = '30/09/2022'

Comment: It's probably the case then that using the sdr_ID filter first is fastest, but the optimizer thinks that doing the date first is fastest.  You could add an index that includes both date and id, or you could run the query without the date filter, look at the query plan to figure out which index it uses to fetch the ScanDataRaw records, and then use a query hint to force it to use this index even when you have the scan date filter in there.

Answer (score 0):

A curiosity:
You should try with the top inside the subquery if you want a faster test and estimation of time.

Some optimizations:

1. Check indexes vs where columns
2. Add Distinct if there are multiple values to reduce the handling
   `select distinct concat(rsw_dept, rsw_rsm_id_fk)`

Here are other ways of handling this:

Test inner join:

```
select top 100 ProductionPeriodic.dbo.ScanDataRaw.* 
from ProductionPeriodic.dbo.ScanDataRaw 
INNER JOIN (
    select distinct concat(rsw_dept, rsw_rsm_id_fk)  as sdr_ID_FILTER
    from [dbo].[RollSheetArchiveDetails] rsad
    inner join dbo.RollSheetMain rsm on rsad.rsw_rsm_id_fk = rsm.rsm_id 
    where rsw_PoNo = 'UHB800008'
    and rsm_status = 'R'
) Filtering
    on sdr_ID =  Filtering.sdr_ID_FILTER
WHERE sdr_ScanDate = '20220930'
```

Test WHERE EXISTS:

```
select top 100 ScanDataRaw.* 
from ProductionPeriodic.dbo.ScanDataRaw AS ScanDataRaw
WHERE sdr_ScanDate = '20220930' 
AND EXISTS 
(select 1   
    from [dbo].[RollSheetArchiveDetails] rsad
    inner join dbo.RollSheetMain rsm on rsad.rsw_rsm_id_fk = rsm.rsm_id 
    where rsw_PoNo = 'UHB800008'
    and rsm_status = 'R' AND concat(rsw_dept, rsw_rsm_id_fk)=ScanDataRaw.sdr_ID
)
```

Comments:
You should use global standardized format 'YYYYMMDD' for dates when defining them into a query and string type column. Best to use date type column and query it with 'YYYY-MM-DD' or dates.

Comment: every part runs well except  WHERE ScanDataRaw.sdr_ScanDate = '30/09/2022'

Comment: @JamesTay I can assume you mean that part is slow, then you should check that column index, keep in mind this important thing, you are telling that column is a string, that is very wrong for two reasons: 1. Index will order first by day and then by month, then by year; which will cause the worst range seeks possible, no optimizations possible for date ranges. 2. Unnecessary overhead with text "/" and string type, if u can, add a simple date column indexed, dates are stored as an integer and you could also query them with the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'